# Max-Width in CSS not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Okay, so I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. I am using wordpress to make a website and am trying to implement a max-width for the site. My style.css is

Edit: The issue is the text runs off the end of the page, it does not break at all.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
    color: #006ec3;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.65em;
}

/* General Layout */
div.container {
    max-width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

The container is being implemented on the site, because it responds to changing of the left padding, but not the right.

Also editting the max-width value shifts the body of the text to the right.

Comment: So, what is wrong? What are you trying to do? What is not working as you expected?

Comment: Just wonder, why do you need to set padding on div.container if you could go with margin instead? margin: 20px auto;

Comment: the text runs off the screen to the right, it doesn't follow the max-width of the site, unless I am misunderstanding the purpose of max-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "margin: 0 auto". Remove this or modify it and it works.
margin: 0 auto is basically centering the content, not pushing anything to the right. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g25md38e/)

```
div.container {
max-width: 500px;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
margin: 0;
```

}

Comment: This does not fix the problem, my text still runs off the page.

Comment: There must be something else causing it, because the css you provided doesn't look like the issue

Comment: Thank you, I seem to have found it, it is a problem with wordpress formatting and not the css, re posting the text causes it to adhere to the css. Thank you!

Comment: If you have any problems with a wordpress css overriding yours, use !important (i.e. max-width: 500px !important;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Then you can define the rules of break lines, ellipsis etc. according to your need:

```
word-break, white-space, etc.
```